# How to make JAX-WS web service secure

Tags: web-services, ssl, jboss, jax-ws

I have got a simple 'Helloworld' JAX-WS service deployed in Jboss 5.1.0. It works fine and I am able to invoke my service from SoapUI client/ Java client.

Now I want to have the service secure(SSL enabled) and access using https protocol. I have done changes to my default\deploy\jbossweb.sar\server.xml file in Jboss

```
  <Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
       port="8443" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
       scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
       keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/ws.keystore"
       keystorePass="install01" sslProtocol = "TLS" />
```

But when I try to do

> > ```
> > https://machinename:8443/abc/webservice?wsdl
> > ```
> >
> > it does not work

any idea?

Comment: "It does not work" doesn't mean anything here. What are the actual symptoms or results of your test?

Answer (score 0):

To make this happen, first, go through some materials those suggests how SSL works. The reason being, when you intends to enable the SSL, then there are rounds of talk that happens between the client and server. On the top of that, there are also terms which are very much specific to SSL. I suggest, go through articles first. Hope this helps.